# How can I remove text in brackets in a string without using regex in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I remove anything inside angle brackets in a string **without** using regex?

For example is I have the following input:

```
var str = "This <is> some <random> text";
```

and would like to obtain the following output:
*This some text*

Comment: What about `var str = "This (is)) some (random) text";`? edit: or `var str = "This ((is) some (random) text";` for that matter?

Comment: why don't you want to use regex?

Comment: I'd like to add that what you're trying to achieve is one of the main reasons why regex exist.

Comment: @zero Yeah you're right, I'm only doing this as an exercise. I'm just starting to learn and just looking trying to get a good grasp on all the basics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Making the assumption that the brackets will line up as in your example, you could do something like this:

```
str = str.split('(')
   .map(function(s) { return s.substring(s.indexOf(')')+1); })
   .join('');
```

Note that, when removing the text within brackets, you are left with double spaces. This seems to match your request since both spaces are in fact outside of your brackets. They could be removed with `.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')`, but that would of course be using regex. If you want to assume that a word within brackets is always followed by a space that is also to be removed, you could do something like this:

```
str = str.split('(')
   .map(function(s) { 
      return s.indexOf(') ') == -1 
         ? s
         : s.substring(s.indexOf(') ') + 2);
    })
   .join('');
```

In this example you need to check for the case where there is no bracket in the string (`"This "`). We didn't need that before, since we always just did +1, and if `indexOf` yielded -1, that would simply mean taking the entire string.

Answer (score 2):

What a strange requirement! This will not use regexp:

```
"This (is) some (random) text".split('(').map(function(el) {
    var i = el.indexOf(')');
    return el = ~i ? el.substr(i) : el;
}).join('('); // This () some () text
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "This (is) some (random) text";

while (str.indexOf('(') != -1) {
    str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('(') - 1) + str.substring(str.indexOf(')') + 1);
}
// Output: This some text
```